# Google Place : exceeded your daily request quota

Tags: android, google-maps

Edit : 01-Nov-11

I am getting some clue about why this might be happening. In my andriod app, when I re-run it after almost a break of 24 hours, it worked for the first time. In fact, when I hit the URL in a browser (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?.....) then also I got the result back.

However, in my app, the text view has a initial text like "Please enter your place name here....". When I used backspace to remove that message and enter a real location, the google api started giving me Over quota error, because I a hitting the api on every click (probably bad programming) and that hit would be more then 10 per second.

Now, what I am looking at is if I am trying again after a break of 10-15 mins still am receiving the same error. Does anyone know how to get out of over quota error?

---

Original Question : 31-Oct-17

I am trying to use google place api in my andriod app. For this, I am making use of google places api call like below

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=*****my_api_key*****&components=country:in&input=mumbai

However, I am getting below message from google

{
   "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.",
   "predictions" : [],
   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}

I have hit the url at the most 10 number of times and that too for over a minute delay. I read from other post of usage limit of 2500 request or less than 100 request per second but I don't believe I am exceeding any of these limits. But still getting above error.

I checked in google developer console and it reports no traffic in past one hour.

Three main questions

1. Can someone please provide a stepwise instruction (possibly with links) to check usage in developer console?
2. Given the above scenario, why would I encounter this error at all (when the usage is way below the specified limit)? How to overcome it?
3. Is it possible, that my andriod app is making these requests in background? If yes, how to confirm this?

Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated.

SandeepG

Comment: 1) When you created a key that needed to be associated with a project, your project dashboard should have info regarding usage. 3) In addition to logging when using calling the API, use a http proxy to monitor. I'm also assuming that the app hasn't been shared with friends or QA team which would explain usage or running in background on emulator/devices you were developing with.

Comment: Thanks Morrison for your reply.      As mentioned, the usage for the key that I am using in the project is showing no traffic in developer console. Also, the app is not shared with anyone. However it does remain installed on my phone. I do not know the way to check if the app is making any background request or not.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to verify your card details although in free to use max free limit.
2. Check the actual statistics in the console for the particular api.